# Not able to play the .wav sound which i recorded through coding in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

i have tried to record the audio in wav format and i succeeded but when i try to play that file, it gives an error that 'media file is of unsupported format'.

the main portion of code is as follows:

```
            player = Manager.createPlayer("capture://audio?encoding=pcm&rate=44100&bits=16&channels=1");
            player.realize();
            controller = (RecordControl) player.getControl("RecordControl");
            controller.setRecordLocation("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/voicenotes/voice.wav");
            //controller.setRecordSizeLimit(396900);
            controller.startRecord();
            player.start();
            Thread.sleep(7000);
            controller.commit();
            player.close();
```

This code works well and it gave me a voice.wav file but i am not able to play this file.Is there is something which i forget?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the same problem as here:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Bug-in-media-Manager-Player/td-p/1009027/page/2

Essentially, you need to add the RIFF/WAVE-header for the recorded data yourself, see the last post on the thread for example.